# Excel formula that multiplies the value of a cell times 2 only if it is under $.99

Tags: excel, math, formula, finance, accounting

Hello and thank you for your help! I am writing a formula to help me calculate coupon deals for my shopping trip.

My store doubles coupons $.99 or under, so I need a formula that does the following:

If the value in cell D2 is less than $1.00, multiply the value by 2 and spit it out in D3.

I tried writing my own formula but it is not working, obviously :( =PRODUCT(IF(D2<"$1.00")D2 * 2)

Any ideas?

Comment: what should happen if cell D2 is not less than $1.00?

Comment: If D2 is over $1.00, then repeat the same value in the cell next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethign like this should do the trick, giving you the double amount if < $1, otherwise giving you the non-doubled amount.

```
=IF(D2<1, D2*2, D2)
```

("," might have to be ";" depending on Excel's whims and localisation settings :) )

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I kept getting a circular reference warning so it ended up looking like this: =IF(D2<1, D2*2, E2)

Is there a way to enhance this so if the value of D2 is $1.00 or over, to just repeat the value in E2 instead?

Comment: I am not sure i am following :) If your coupon value is in D2, and this formula is in E2, my original would work without circular reference. If you put your formula in E2, it won't work. The D2/E2 at the end is simply the value you want if the coupon value in D2 is >$1.

Comment: Your current formula with E2 (what cell are you putting that in?) _is_ "repeating"(?) the value from E2 f the value in D2 > 1 by the way.

Comment: You are right. I tried putting the formula in D2 at first, got the error, moved and edited it to E2. I put the original in D2 and it does exactly what I want. You rock thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Providing you have the value of the cells formatted with $ a the start, the following should work when entered into cell D3:

```
=IF((D2<"$1.00"),D2 * 2,D2)
```

If the cells are formatted as numbers to 2 d.p use the following:

```
=IF((D2<1.00),D2 * 2,D2)
```

Thanks